# Which command will executed first,If a stored procedure have individual multiple select commands;

Tags: sql-server-2005

Which command will executed first,If a stored procedure have individual multiple select commands;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands inside stored procedure are executed in the order in which they are written.